# Django ImageField Override the File Collision Code

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have 2 ImageFields in a Model.

1. being the one where the user uploads an image
2. being one where we have a copy of that image, but using the Same File.

Note: I am simplfying the reason for the two fields.

Apart from Creating a new ImageField field type is there any way to stop the ImageField adding a _ to the filename, when we assign the second field programatically?

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason you're not using a filefield for the second entry? It doesn't sound like you're using the specifics of an image field (that is, the admin verifies that it's an image on upload) for that second item. If you need it to be an image field for some reason in your code, you could cast it...

I assume you've got the second field set to hidden in the admin interface?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am hiding the second field in the admin interface. The FileField still does the filename collision as far as I know. I need to keep them the same, but field type for an external team using second field in an API.

I will look into other options, thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I know you say "apart from creating a new `ImageField` type", but I'd imagine that the best way to do this would be to do just that, and [override the `get_filename` method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L275) of `FileField` (which `ImageField` obviously subclasses).

Apart from that, it is possible to create your own `Storage` (`django.core.files.storage`) subclass, which you would pass as the `storage` argument to the `ImageField` in your mode. You would need to override the [`get_valid_name` method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/files/storage.py#L54) there. To note is that the actual underscores come from the [`get_valid_filename` method in `django.utils.text`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/text.py#L115).

I really don't what's wrong with subclassing `ImageField` to provide the necessary functionality, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Basically I was looking to see if there was a configuration/parameter change that could help